# Autoregistrered server deletion

Tags: zabbix

I work with Zabbix. I have two servers which active checks were working perfectly but that I did accidentally delete.

I thought that as they were correctly working before, they would pop up on the hosts list again on their own, but three hours have passed by and still the servers were not auto registered again.

I want to emphasize that they were working perfectly until I deleted them. When  I see the log, I see this :

```
  2113:20180801:125559.623 cannot send list of active checks to "192.168.43.216": host [Centos_7_VM] not found
  2111:20180801:125634.323 cannot send list of active checks to "192.168.43.236": host [Ubuntu_1604_VM] not found
```

Also, I can see they are in green status on the Monitoring -> Discovery screen so they are detected by the servers, they simply are not added back to the system.

How can I revert this? Is this related to the housekeeping process? How can I make this process run manually?

Comment: For hosts to automatically appear either network discovery or active agent auto-registration must be set up (at least these are the most popular options). Did you use one of those?

Comment: @Richlv Thanks so much for your response. As an update to this, just like that, after 4 hours, both of the servers popped up. I hit that refresh button on Firefox like a million times and then suddenly, it seems they are online again. My only question then, how can I control this? Is there some process that I can hurry up to not having to wait until things suddenly "appear" ?

Comment: Having no idea on how your discovery or registration process is set up, this is impossible to answer. I'd suggest pursuing the channels at https://zabbix.org/wiki/Getting_help , with IRC being a great option.